# How to work with large .jld data files in Julia

Tags: julia, large-data, large-files

I have some files of the `.jld` Julia file format which have multidimensional arrays. In my drive, the files totally take up around 60 GB. I want to concatenate some of them together using `hcat()` and then do further calculations and plots from these data files.

However, just to read these files either takes very long, or I get an "Out of Memory Error" so I'm not sure how to work with these files. I have 8 GB RAM in my device, and I am loading the data out of an external HDD (I also prepared the data from simulations and wrote them directly to this HDD but there were no errors then).

How do I deal with files this large?

Answer (score 3):

In order to work with data larger than your memory you need to use to have disk-based data structures.
Julia supports this functionality via `mmap` (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap/)

Fortunately, a higher level interface is also available via `SharedArrays` (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/):

Hence, you can do:

```
using SharedArrays
a = SharedArray{Float64}("c:\\temp\\file.dat", (100,100,100))
```

Now you have a disk-backed array. You can copy your JLD data into it and perform the aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I am trying to install the `SharedArray` package using `Pkg.add("SharedArray")`, which is how I normally install a new package for the first time, but this gives me an error `* SharedArray (not found in project, manifest or registry)`. I'm not sure what this means, and I'm quite new to Julia. How should I be installing this package?

Comment: it is `SharedArrays` - it is part of Julia core (typo on my side)

Comment: You may also want to consider something like https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StackViews.jl for the concatenation